# Is the second word in phrases like "throw out" and "write down" a preposition or adverb?

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, phrasal-verbs, parts-of-speech

There are a couple of places where I get confused on whether a word is an adverb or a preposition (or maybe even both?). For example, a sentence I am confused by is

> "Don't throw **out** the water bottle!"

In this context, some people in my class think that "out" is a preposition, and that "out the water bottle" is the prepositional phrase in the sentence. However, other people think that it is an adverb describing where one is throwing. Similarly, another example is

> "Please don't write **down** my answer!"

Here, is "down" an adverb, or a prepositional phase, and why is it that way? Do these questions have a right/wrong, or is it more like a gray area? Is there a specific logic behind it?

Comment: These particles are the linguistic counterpart to Einstein's "spooky action at a distance".

Answer (score 2):

They are both prepositions.

In the first, *out* does not form a phrase with *the water bottle* as it is possible to switch their position:

> Don't throw **out** the water bottle.
>
> Don't throw the water bottle **out**.

Its function here is a particle - a single word that is allowed in combination with a particular verb. Particles can be verbs, adjectives, or prepositions. These can switch places with the object.

> They cut **short** the seminar. [adjective]
>
> They cut the seminar **short**.
>
> He let **slip** a very intriguing detail. [verb]
>
> He let a very intriguing detail **slip**.
>
> She wrote **down** the answer. [preposition]
>
> She wrote the answer **down**.

Their category is irrelevant from the point of view of modification or complementation as they cannot take (or are at least extremely limited in their range of) dependents when functioning as a particle.

Still, there is no reason to reassign these words to the adverb category simply because they are functioning as a direct dependent of a verb - complements in this case, not modifiers, as they are only allowed by a very specific subset of verbs.

This is similar to nouns acting as dependents in noun phrases and not being reassigned to the adjective category. Few would argue that *school* in the sentence below is an adjective.

> We got on the ***school*** bus.

In general, *down* and *out* are best analyzed as prepositions as they are able to modify nouns regardless of whether they are used by themselves or with dependents. This is something most will agree adverbs cannot do.

> [The hike **out**] wasn't long.
>
> [The view **out the side ports**] spoke volumes.
>
> [The way **down**] was lit with candles.
>
> I'm just going to buy [the house **down the block**].

Comment: I prefer to see such particles as a separate class; they are far removed from the prototypical prepositions.  CGEL correctly rejects FANBOYS on such grounds.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "Particle" is a grammatical relation like "subject" or "object." CGEL spends so much time talking about particles because they aren't all prepositions. Some are adjectives and some are adverbs (the ones that behave like adverbs! Not the ones that behave like prepositions).

Comment: @Araucaria ' "Particle" is a grammatical relation like "subject" ' in some treatments. But [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_particle) has << In modern grammar, a particle is a function word that must be associated with another word or phrase to impart meaning, i.e., it does not have its own lexical definition.[citation needed] According to this definition, particles are a separate part of speech.  >>This too is an arrogation. And I'd not class the  infinitive marker 'to' alongside the MWV particle 'to' in 'heave to'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That Wiki article is a car crash unfortunately. And not one reference where it would count. But the main reason for my comment is that DW makes it clear that's how they're using the word, by stating that "it's function here is *particle*" and "when functioning as a particle" etc, etc and also by contrasting them with modifiers and DOs. But yes, some writers (generally those who cannot keep their PoS and functions separate in the first place) class *particles* from phrasal verbs as a PoS. Granted.

Comment: Although you're right that most people will agree that adverbs cannot postmodify nouns, H&P wouldn't. Although they don't *freely* modify nouns, they quite often do: "The explosion recently was predicted by scientists three years ago" etc See this interesting paper: [Payne, Huddleston & Pullum: The distribution and category status of adjectives and adverbs](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/E1750124510000486.pdf).  See Section 5 **Adverbs as postmodifiers of nouns** p. 42.

Comment: 'Arriving at the embarkation point for the ferry six hours early, we drove on'. Is 'on' the 'intransitive preposition' relict of 'drove on[to] the ferry', or is it the equivalent of 'further [into town, say''? I'm unhappy with the dustbinning of the preposition class.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Interesting article indeed! A significant caveat to a general test delimiting prepositions and adverbs. Can always double check using the sole complement in a complex-intrasitive headed by _**be**_ test: _The lights were **out**_ / *_The lights were **brokenly**_. Still, even per the article, adverbs are limited and rather rare as modifiers in NPs, whereas prepositions (with objects or not) are extremely common.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth On the contrary! The preposition class is alive and well. In fact, now that it is clear that an NP object is not a requirement for membership, prepositions have been better distinguished from other classes, eliminating the need for multiple part of speech entries in dictionaries and increasing the accuracy of corpus searches where an adverb wildcard should no longer return prepositions!

Answer (score 1):

Some people call them *prepositions*, and other people call them *adverbs*, and a significant number of people give them yet a different name: **particles**. But only if they undergo Particle Shift:

- *Throw the water bottle out! ~ Throw out the water bottle!* (OK either side of NP object)
- *Throw it out!*, but not **Throw out it!* (Only OK after pronoun object)

Here's the list of particles that undergo the rule:

- *up/down, in/out, on/off, over/under, through, by, past, to, about, across, along, around, behind*

There are also a few other words that are hard to call prepositions because they never head a PP: *back, forth, away, apart, aside, together*. These also undergo the rule:

- *Throw away the bottle/Throw the bottle away/Throw it away*, but not **Throw away it*.

And here are the undoubted prepositions:
*aboard, above, after, against, amid, among, anent, at, atop, before, below, beneath, beside, between, beyond, but, circa, concerning, despite, during, except, for, from, inside, into, notwithstanding, of, onto, opposite, outside, pending, per, save, since, till, toward(s), underneath, until, unto, upon, via, with, within, without,* etc.

All these are bad in the frame: `V NP` __

- **I nailed the lamp above*
- **We threw marshmallows at*
- **I washed the car before*
- **You should leave the car between*

As to what you wanna call them, suit yourself. Nobody cares (except teachers, if you're still in school) because such grammatical terms are always arbitrary and represent the prejudices of the grammarian using them. Hence as long as you're consistent, you can use any term you like.

Comment: Came [right back]. [Back [from the edge]]. She's [back home]. <--- They're PP's, though.

Comment: How about *took it inside* / *put it underneath* / *kept it within*? And *I've washed the car before* seems okish to me too. Fiddly, these small words, aren't they.

Answer (score -1):

***Out*** is a preposition in prepositional phrases like

> - throw ***out*** *the widow* (the window is the **prepositional object** of ***out***)
> - ran ***out*** *the door*
> - ran ***down** the hill*

But ***out*** is an adverb or what some grammarians call *a prepositional adverb* in sentences similar to yours:

> - ***throw out*** the bottle (*the bottle* is the **direct object** of the VP ***throw out***, NOT the prepositional object of ***out***)
> - ***carried out*** the job
> - ***write down*** the answer

[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/prepositional-adverb-1691528) quotes *The Elements of English Grammar* by George Philip Krapp, who explains

> The difference between the ***pure preposition*** and ***the prepositional adverb*** is illustrated by the following two sentences:
>
> - He ran ***up the stairs***.
> - He ***ran up*** a bill.
>
> In the first sentence, a prepositional phrase, ***stairs*** is the object of ***up***. The expression ***up the stairs*** is a prepositional phrase modifying the verb *ran*. In the second sentence, however, ***bill*** *is not the object of* ***up*** and ***up a bill*** is, therefore, *not a prepositional phrase* modifying the verb *ran*.
>
> Rather, the word ***up*** is acting as a ***prepositional adverb*** modifying the verb ***ran***. Together, the two words form the phrasal verb ***ran up***, an expression whose distinct meaning has nothing to do with the act of running (Krapp 1970).

Comment: There's something inelegant about these Frankenstein categories that conflate parts of speech with labels for function in clause structure. Also note the lack of reasoning: the labels are just applied as though it's clear to everyone why it must be so.

Comment: Throw out the widow? Why what did she do? And even if it's a typo for *window* who typically throws out windows? Please, can you **come up with** something more natural-sounding?

Comment: Crystal came up with the term 'lexeme' for 'strings behaving as a single word' (as well as to cover {throw, throws ...}), and many of the multi-word verbs in this category have single-word synonyms ('carry out' = 'perform / execute'; 'throw out' = 'discard'; 'write down' = 'inscribe / record / notate' ...). I tend to see 'run up' [a bill] as a unary transitive MWV; if 'up' here needs a name, I just use 'particle in a MWV'.

Comment: How can "The elements of English grammar, by Krapp" not be a satirical spoof?

Answer (score -2):

Lots and none at all.

"Out" is prepositional, not adverbial, but "out the water bottle" is a misunderstanding, not a phrase.

If they're to be separated then "out" belongs not with the bottle but necessarily with "throw."

It might in some odd circumstance be possible to use "The bottle out…" as an answer to "What was thrown?" but those circumstances would pretty-much be limited to discussions of grammar and syntax, not to actual speech.

I suggest you'll find more help on Question like this in English Language Learning

Comment: I think a question about words that are particles functioning as complement of a verb in a transitive clause is better suited to ELU than ELL.

Comment: @BillJ On a level using that language, I'd agree… only, Kong wasn't.